# URI malformed in React Project - Using Parcel Bundler

Tags: reactjs, parcel

I am experimenting with React project and parcel as the bundler.
I am getting this error trying to run the command "dev":

****Server running at http://localhost:1234
×  C:\React\parcelreact\todoapp\public\index.html: URI malformed****

This is a standard create-react-app project then added parcel-bundler..

This is my package.json "scripts" {}

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "dev": "parcel public/index.html",
    "run": "parcel build index.html"
  },
```

C:\React\parcelreact\todoapp\public\index.html: URI malformed
at decodeURIComponent ()

What is the cause of this error?
My index.html is indeed inside my public/ folder..

Help.?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm trying to do the same thing and receiving the same error.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is due to all of the values in the public/index.html that create-react-app creates that contains "%PUBLIC_URL%".  If you modify these paths to be relative paths to the files they are pointing to you should be able to run your app using Parcel just fine.

Comment: Thanks, a lot Brian! I appreciate it